# html increase elements width based on the percentage of browser size increased

Tags: html, css, variables

I have some question about html and css.

Here are the case. I'm building a mobile web, which my base line is 240px width. So all my elements's dimension is set base on the 240 screen size. But when I view the web in a larger phone like Samsung Galaxy note. All things seem to be too small for user to click on it.

Now the question, is it possible to use variable kind of css for width and height ??
Lets say, the thumbnail I use in 240px width device is 50px, so when I view my thumbnail in a 480px width device, the thumbnail will be display in 100px, which means the thumbnail will be increase its size based on the percentage of the screen increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, obviously you can, what you are looking for is called [Responsive Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/), to accomplish that, you will need `@media` queries.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKDh5/) *(Resize the window to see the effect)*

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
}

@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    div {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Alien.
Is it possible to use something like.
var thumbWidth = 50px

.thumbnail{
     width:'thumbWidth';
}

Comment: @mok_ku no you cannot, but you can take a look at css pre processors like LESS or SASS, but that will will just compile the stylesheets for you, it wont calculate anything for you on runtime

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Alien, then I properly have to follow the media queries way, like what previous answer said.

Comment: @mok_ku You welcome :) and actually I had already answered, he just replicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for your width instead of fixed width to make the images responsive.

For example, use 100% instead of 50px. It will automatically fill the container (in which the container is also responsive) and automatically resize on your browser.

Comment: Thanks @D. WONG,
  Is it possible to make the height in % also ??
Like I make the div 20% width. But I want the height follow the width of the div.

Answer (score 0):

yes ,it is possible,responsive design achieve in following ways,

1. All dimension in `%`
2. **[media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/)**

Comment: `%` is required for fluidness, nothing to do with responsive design, you can use any desired unit

Comment: hmm, is it possible to achieve it without media queries ?? like using a "var" in javascript or jquery ??

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `@media` queries for responsive design

example:

```
div{
width: 50px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px){

div{
width: 100px;
}
```

}

(or) u can also use percentages at certain cases like `width: 20%`